# JPA - Create flat entity with multiple tables joined

Tags: java, jpa, olingo

I'm trying to join two tables that have the same id into a plain entity.

After some research found out @SecondaryTable would do the trick.

However, I'm getting the following error:
Exception Description: The table ["PLAYER"] is not present in this descriptor.

Below is the current version of source code.

```
@Entity(name = "PlayerConfig")
@Table(schema = "x", name = "\"PLAYER_CONFIG\"")
@SecondaryTable(schema = "b", name = "\"PLAYER\"", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "PLAYER_ID", referencedColumnName = "player_id"))
public class PlayerConfig {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "player_id")
    private int playerId;

    @Column(name = "CURRENT_TEAM_ID", table = "\"PLAYER\"")
    private int teamId;

    .. getters and setters
}
```

The tables are configured as follows:

```
      <createTable schemaName="x" tableName="PLAYER_CONFIG">    
        <column name="player_id" type="INT">
           <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>   
      </createTable>

      <createTable schemaName="b" tableName="PLAYER">   
        <column name="PLAYER_ID" type="INT">
           <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>   
        <column name="CURRENT_TEAM_ID" type="INT"/>
    </createTable>
```

Any ideas?

This is working with @JoinColumn, but I need to create a flat entity in order to later on use it on Apache Olingo and other frameworks.

Comment: Do you *intend* to specify a table name that contains literal double quote characters?

Comment: Yes, this is needed due to database specifics. I cannot change table names.

Comment: Have removed the quotes and it worked... Guess this might be a bug on JPA as it works fine for @JoinColumn... Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: If it works for `@JoinColumn` in the sense of successfully referencing a column name that *does not* contain literal quotation mark characters, then *that* is the bug.  You should not be trying to embed SQL syntax into names expressed to JPA.  It is the JPA implementation's responsibility to perform proper quoting in conjunction with the JDBC driver in use.

Comment: @JohnBollinger can you please post your comment as answer so that this question no longer appears as unanswer. Thank you

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, I think it more appropriate to close the question as off-topic on the basis of arising from a typographical error.  I have so voted, as did one person before me.

Comment: @JohnBollinger agree. Voted too